# Clearing Repeating CSS Classes

Tags: css

I have a very long CSS file because i have merged a couple of separate style sheets. Now i can see the repating classes on DOM Inspector but detecting and deleting the one by one is very hard.

I found some CSS minifiers on internet like https://cssminifier.com/ which is minifying the code and cleaning the multiple classes but since i am newbie it is very hard to read or edit them for me.

I have think of regex but so far i achived nothing. I am open to any kind of solution which does not include back-end coding.

Comment: You can then unminify your css code [here](http://unminify.com/) so you can make edits.

Comment: Minify and unminify operations may help to clear. Generally minify tools groups classes those have same css rules. Hopefully it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found another solution and i've just wanted to share it, worked very well for me.

I've installed Node.js and installed CSS Pure:

```
npm install css-purge -g
```

Right after i have put my CSS file to somewhere that i can access easily, like C:\MyCSSFiles and run the following code inside that directory:

```
css-purge -i myFile.css -o myFile_purged.css
```

i stands for the name of the input file, and o stands for the name of the output file.

This process had removed the comments on the code tho... It is ok for me anyways.

Comment: Hey @yeşim-ela-gülcan, we just updated CSS-PURGE! :) ~ http://rbtech.github.io/css-purge